# Understanding *x ,= lst

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

I'm going through some old code trying to understand what it does, and I came across this odd statement:

```
*x ,= p
```

`p` is a list in this context. I've been trying to figure out what this statement does. As far as I can tell, it just sets `x` to the value of `p`. For example:

```
p = [1,2]
*x ,= p    
print(x)
```

Just gives

```
[1, 2]
```

So is this any different than `x = p`? Any idea what this syntax is doing?

Comment: It's different because instead of assigning an alias, it copies the list.

Comment: See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/

Comment: Omitting the comma gives an error message to which this might be an interesting reference: "SyntaxError: starred assignment target must be in a list or tuple".

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`*x ,= p` is basically an obfuscated version of `x = list(p)` using [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/). The comma after `x` is required to make the assignment target a tuple (it could also be a list though).

`*x, = p` **is** different from `x = p` because the former creates a *copy* of `p` (i.e. a new list) while the latter creates a *reference* to the original list. To illustrate:

```
>>> p = [1, 2]
>>> *x, = p 
>>> x == p
True
>>> x is p
False
>>> x = p
>>> x == p
True
>>> x is p
True
```

Comment: Also worth noting that the comma actually belongs to the `*x`, as the starred assignment must be in a list or tuple. So the more explicit way to write that statement is `(*x,) = p`

Comment: Important to note, this works when `p` is *any* iterable.

Comment: Might be worth adding something like `x[0] = 3; p #=> [1, 2]` to the first half and `x[0] = 3; p #=> [3, 2]` to the second, to illustrate why `is` and `==` are different

Answer (score 52):

It's a feature that was introduced in Python 3.0 ([PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)). In Python 2, you could do something like this:

```
>>> p = [1, 2, 3]
>>> q, r, s = p
>>> q
1
>>> r
2
>>> s
3
```

Python 3 extended this so that one variable could hold multiple values:

```
>>> p = [1, 2, 3]
>>> q, *r = p
>>> q
1
>>> r
[2, 3]
```

This, therefore, is what is being used here. Instead of two variables to hold three values, however, it is just one variable that takes each value in the list. This is different from `x = p` because `x = p` just means that `x` is another name for `p`. In this case, however, it is a new list that just happens to have the same values in it. (You may be interested in ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/5827958))

Two other common ways of producing this effect are:

```
>>> x = list(p)
```

and

```
>>> x = p[:]
```

Since Python 3.3, the list object actually has a method intended for copying:

```
x = p.copy()
```

The slice is actually a very similar concept. As nneonneo pointed out, however, that works only with objects such as lists and tuples that support slices. The method you mention, however, works with any iterable: dictionaries, sets, generators, etc.

Comment: Note, though, that your second bit of code, `x = p[:]` requires that `p` be slice-able. This excludes things like generators.

Comment: Wait, 3.0!? I thought it was way more recent, 3.5 or 3.6 or something.

Comment: @user2357112: In [What's New In Python 3.0](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/whatsnew/), you will find this bullet point: `PEP 3132 was accepted`. In addition, the PEP itself says the Python version is 3.0. I'm pretty sure that must be the case, then.

Comment: @zondo In Python3, the slicing method of copying has a [new more readable counterpart](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17810305/3745896) that you might include instead since this question only applies to Python3. (Though only Python 3.3 and up have it.)

Comment: @River: Ah, yes. I had forgotten about that one. I kept the slice because it is useful for more than just lists and is still a commonly-seen tactic, but I added the `.copy` method.

Answer (score 16):

You should always throw these to [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) and see what it throws back at you; you'll see how `*x, = p` is actually different from `x = p`:

```
dis('*x, = p')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (p)
              2 UNPACK_EX                0
              4 STORE_NAME               1 (x)
```

While, the simple assignment statement:

```
dis('x = p')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (p)
              2 STORE_NAME               1 (x)
```

<sup>(Stripping off unrelated `None` returns)</sup>

As you can see `UNPACK_EX` is the different op-code between these; [it's documented as](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-UNPACK_EX):

> Implements assignment with a starred target: Unpacks an iterable in TOS (top of stack) into individual values, where the total number of values can be smaller than the number of items in the iterable: one of the new values will be a list of all leftover items.

Which is why, as Eugene noted, you get a new object that's referred to by the name `x` and not a reference to an already existing object (as is the case with `x = p`).

---

`*x,` does seem very odd (the extra comma there and all) but it is required here. The left hand side must either be a tuple or a list and, due to the quirkiness of creating a single element tuple in Python, you need to use a trailing `,`:

```
i = 1, # one element tuple
```

If you like confusing people, you can always use the `list` version of this:

```
[*x] = p
```

which does exactly the same thing but doesn't have that extra comma hanging around there.

Answer (score 4):

**You can clearly understand it from below example**

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4]
while L:
    temp, *L = L             
    print(temp, L)
```

what it does is, the front variable will get the first item every time and the remaining list will be given to L.

The output will look shown below.

```
1 [2, 3, 4]
2 [3, 4]
3 [4]
4 []
```

Also look at below example

```
x, *y, z = "python"
print(x,y,z)
```

In this both x,z will get each one letter from the string meaning first letter is assigned to x and the last letter will be assigned to z and the remaining string will be assigned to variable y.

```
p ['y', 't', 'h', 'o'] n
```

One more example,

```
a, b, *c = [0,1,2,3]
print(a,b,c)

0 1 [2,3]
```

**Boundary case: If there is nothing remaining for star variable then it will get an empty list.**

Example:

```
a,b=[1]
print(a,b)

1 []
```